# Service doesnot start - ArgumentNullException value cannot be null parameter name ip

Tags: service, .net-remoting

Service does not start - `ArgumentNullException value cannot be null parameter name ip`.
My Service does not start and I see following exception in the EventViewer.

```
Service cannot be started. System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Remoting configuration failed with the exception 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ip
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
```

When I debug, the exception happened at line :

```
-> RemotingConfiguration.Configure(configFile, false);
```

My configfile Remoting Configuration is as below:

```
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <service>
        <wellknown mode="Singleton" objectUri="PersonalityModule.rem" type="Ideas.Instructor.PersonalityModules.SPPA.PersonalityModule, PM_SPPA"/>
      </service>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" port="7676"  >
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" /> 
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
```

I have limited knowledge on Remoting. I am not understanding what is causing this error and how to fix it. Kindly suggest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: More info : This exception occurs only when I am not connected to my office network.